# Input type file no webview - Xcode

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, iphone, file-permission

Criei um webview de uma página que contem um input type file para subir fotos, porém, no webview do Iphone, quando clico no botão para subir a foto, ele abre um menu somente com a opção de "Fotos da galeria", e não dá a opção da camera.
Pesquisando na internet vi que preciso liberar o acesso a camera e a galeria de fotos através do arquivo info.plist.
Inserindo as Keys para liberar a camera e a galeria

```
<key>NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription</key>
<string>This app requires access to the photo library.</string>
<key>NSCameraUsageDescription</key>
<string>This app requires access to the camera.</string>
```

Quando clico no botão ele funciona da mesma forma. Me da somente a opção de galeria e não a da camera.
Quando clico na opção de galeria ele fecha o app, então essa liberação da galeria também não funcionou.

Talvez possa ser a ordem das keys, ja tentei ficar mudando a ordem delas, mas também não consegui.
O info.plist esta assim:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>CFBundleDevelopmentRegion</key>
    <string>$(DEVELOPMENT_LANGUAGE)</string>
    <key>CFBundleExecutable</key>
    <string>$(EXECUTABLE_NAME)</string>
    <key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
    <string>$(PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER)</string>
    <key>CFBundleInfoDictionaryVersion</key>
    <string>6.0</string>
    <key>CFBundleName</key>
    <string>$(PRODUCT_NAME)</string>
    <key>CFBundlePackageType</key>
    <string>APPL</string>
    <key>CFBundleShortVersionString</key>
    <string>1.0</string>
    <key>CFBundleVersion</key>
    <string>1</string>
    <key>LSRequiresIPhoneOS</key>
    <true/>
    <key>UILaunchStoryboardName</key>
    <string>LaunchScreen</string>
    <key>UIMainStoryboardFile</key>
    <string>Main</string>
    <key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations~ipad</key>
    <array>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
    </array>
    <key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations</key>
    <array>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
    </array>
    <key>UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities</key>
    <array>
        <string>armv7</string>
    </array>
    <key>NSCameraUsageDescription</key>
    <string>Para tirar a foto precisamos de acesso a camera</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Estou usando o Xcode 9.2 e rodando o emulador do Iphone 8.

Alguém poderia me ajudar?

Grato

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você precisa adicionar permissões no arquivo **Info.plist**.

**Camera:**

```
Key       :  Privacy - Camera Usage Description   
Value     :  $(PRODUCT_NAME) camera use
```

**Photo:**

```
Key       :  Privacy - Photo Library Usage Description    
Value     :  $(PRODUCT_NAME) photo use
```

Comment: Estava fazendo isso mas não funcionava, dai tentei fazer o teste através de um iphone ao invés do emulador de iphone e funcionou. Ele só não funciona no emulador aqui pra mim.

Comment: @gabriel qual a versão do swift e iOS você está utilizando ?